# html file upload:Can we detect that browser did not send request for file larger than 2GB (IE / FF)?

Tags: html, file-upload

I know that IE & FF don't support file uploads larger than 2 GB. But can we somehow get to know that browser did not send request for a file larger than 2 GB?
I am using GWT upload panel. When we attach a file larger than 2 GB and submit the form,IE fires onSubmitComplete even but event.getResults() is null. event.getResults() is also null when internet disconnects.
Firefox does on even fire this event.

Is it possible to detect (at client side via some event or error) that upload has failed due to size limit?

Regards,
Nadeem Ullah

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check the file size before trying to upload it? If it's greater than 2GB, send a warning to the user ...

Comment: How is supposed to do that? In javascript?

Comment: Hey Olivier, How can we detect file size in an html application via javascript, without using a plugin?